# Getting one-to-many string results as columns in a combined query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Using SQL Server. This seems kind of like a Pivot maybe with ROW_NUMBER but I'm having a lot of trouble with the learning curve to figure out all the parts that would make that work over my 2 tables.

Table A has a row for each ITEM (by Id). I need a few columns values from this table in my results.

Table B has multiple rows for each ITEM with each row describing a different configuration setting value for the item. Each configuration setting has a Name and a Value. There are a few different setting Names that I want to pull from Table B and display the matching setting Value in a column in my result set.

```
Table A
ID        |   Name
1001      | William
1002      | Patricia

Table B
ID        | ItemID   | Setting   | Value
999       |  1001    | EyeColor  | Blue
998       |  1001    | Nickname  | Billy
997       |  1002    | Nickname  | Trish
996       |  1002    | EyeColor  | Green

Desired Result
ItemID    | Name    | EyeColor   |  Nickname
1001      | William | Blue       | Billy
1002      | Patricia| Green      | Trish
```

What I'm currently doing to get this result (and it works) is:

```
SELECT 
    A.ID, 
    A.Name, 
    'EyeColor' = (SELECT B.Value FROM B WHERE B.ItemID = A.ID AND B.Setting = 'EyeColor'),
    'Nickname' = (SELECT B.Value FROM B WHERE B.ItemID = A.ID AND B.Setting = 'Nickname')
FROM TableA as A
WHERE (some criteria that filters on values in Table A)
```

But this seems klunky and I kind of wonder if this might not scale well to a result set with 2000 items in Table A's result set.

Suggestions for a better way to do this?

Comment: Pretty sure that is as good as it gets... there is no shortcut.

Comment: It is klunky because that is not a properly normalized schema. You have an EAV design (search the web for more information) - you now have a better understanding of why that "flexibility" comes with a significant penalty.

Comment: The only other solution just as clunky and may or may not be more performant: join the tables and group by ID, Name then select `MIN(CASE WHEN B.Setting = 'EyeColor' THEN B.VALUE END)`

Answer (score 0):

group by the item id and load the data in the EyeColor and NickName column

unpivot is equivalent to pythons melt

```
declare @tmp as table(ItemID int, EyeColor varchar(20), NickName varchar(20))

insert into @tmp(ItemID, EyeColor,NickName)
Values(1001    , 'Blue','Billy')
,( 1002    ,'Green'  , 'Trish')

select * from @tmp

select ItemID,Variables
from
(select ItemID,EyeColor,NickName from @tmp) source
UNPIVOT
(Variables for Setting in (EyeColor,NickName)) as unpvt


 ItemID EyeColor    NickName
 1001   Blue    Billy
 1002   Green   Trish

 ItemID Variables
 1001   Blue
 1001   Billy
 1002   Green
 1002   Trish



 declare @tmp2 as table(ID int, ItemID int, Setting varchar(20), Data varchar(20))

 insert into @tmp2(ID,ItemID, Setting, Data)
 Values(1,1001, 'EyeColor','Blue')
 ,(2,1001,'NickName','Billy')
 ,(3,1002,'EyeColor','Green')   
 ,(4,1002,'NickName','Trish')   

 select ItemID, Max(Case When Setting='EyeColor' then Data End) EyeColor,
    Max(Case When Setting='NickName' then Data End) NickName
    from @tmp2
    group by ItemID

  ItemID    EyeColor    NickName
  1001      Blue    Billy
  1002     Green    Trish
```

Comment: Can you suggest a reference that explains how to use PIVOT when you don't want to aggregate? The syntax from MS specifically talks about aggregating (e.g. COUNT,MIN,MAX) but from what I can tell, I'm not trying to aggregate anything.

Comment: Pivot only works if you have an column to aggregate  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15#unpivot-example

Comment: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/switching-rows-and-columns-in-sql/   you can use case when to square the data, but it is code intensive.  It is better to load the data in square form